# Why does PlaceAutocompleteFragment crashes with NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to find place from Google map in my android 
my code is

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());

            String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                    + place.getId() + "\n"
                    + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                    + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                    + place.getAttributions();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

but when I try to enter something it crashes with error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                    Process: com.example.asset.lab13_bonus, PID: 1192
                                                                         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbo(Landroid/content/Context;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability' appears in /data/app/com.example.asset.lab13_bonus-bAk1S6P8t8HToIo1FR8JeA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes12.dex)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.zza$zza.build(Unknown Source:79)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete$IntentBuilder.build(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment.zzboi(Unknown Source:42)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment$1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Gradle dependencies :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0"
```

what does this mean ?
Can someone help me?
May be it does not work because of device?

Comment: add your gradle dependecy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make sure all your dependencies are the same version to avoid conflicts, whether it be 9.4.0 or 11.0.4.  Older versions could work fine but you might be missing out on some features the newer ones provide.